# R & XML - format dataframe correctly

Tags: xml, r, nodes

I want to create a dataframe from an XML file. I only need specific nodes and want to arrange them in a way I can easily work with the data.

I am only interested in the content of the different `<stroke>` nodes.
What I need are `<starttime>` and `<endtime>`, also `<bounds>` with all subnodes and all `<sample>` nodes with `<x>`, `<y>` and `<time>` subnodes.

This is my current code:

```
file <- "1.xml"
xmlfile <- xmlTreeParse(file)
xmltop <- xmlRoot(xmlfile)
values <- xmlSApply(xmltop, function(x) xmlSApply(x, xmlValue))
df <- data.frame(t(values),row.names=NULL)
```

The interesting part of the data-frame containing the stroke data looks like this:

`UnassignedStrokes
1 1459867893629, 1459867896812, 145986789362914598678948151.0-14090101260.0750.0217.018.0260.625766.01459867893629108260.625763.6251459867893722120262.875762.01459867893775122278.0757.1251459867893935124294.875755.751459867894015124304.875755.1251459867894055124319.125755.3751459867894109124326.75754.751459867894135124355.0756.51459867894229124372.375756.3751459867894282124388.625755.3751459867894335124401.375756.1251459867894375124427.75754.3751459867894469124448.75752.1251459867894549124455.5750.8751459867894575124473.75751.251459867894669124476.125752.01459867894789124474.25751.751459867894802118469.875750.7514598678948150, 145986789589214598678968121.0-14090101364.0701.010.0125.0364.5701.0145986789589232366.0702.01459867895905106367.25702.6251459867895958120367.5703.1251459867896012122369.25724.1251459867896358126369.375748.01459867896465126370.125765.01459867896532126369.875779.51459867896598126369.125789.1251459867896638126369.375795.251459867896665126370.875803.751459867896705126373.125825.6251459867896812126`.

It seems like that all the values of the subnodes are queued up, making it hard to work with it. What has happened there and what can I do to format this correctly?

This is a snapshot of my XML data:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<page>
  <id>1459867896812</id>
  <bookId>1459867896812</bookId>
  <paperspace>21.49.16.203</paperspace>
  <checkDate>2016-04-05 16:51:36.812</checkDate>
  <penCheckDate>2016-04-05 16:51:36.812</penCheckDate>
  <receiveDate>2016-04-05 16:51:48.363</receiveDate>
  <pageNr>203</pageNr>
  <pages>1</pages>
  <processStatus>received</processStatus>
  <penData>
    <expiration>0</expiration>
    <signature/>
    <toEnterprise>1</toEnterprise>
    <company>Universitaet Muenster</company>
    <mandator>Uni_Muenster</mandator>
    <comment>Universitaet Muenster</comment>
    <pagesToComplete/>
    <previousPages>0</previousPages>
    <clientAttribute name="vertrag">XXXX</clientAttribute>
  </penData>
  <bounds>
    <x>260.0</x>
    <y>701.0</y>
    <width>217.0</width>
    <height>125.0</height>
  </bounds>
  <UnassignedStrokes>
    <starttime>1459867893629</starttime>
    <endtime>1459867896812</endtime>
    <stroke>
      <starttime>1459867893629</starttime>
      <endtime>1459867894815</endtime>
      <linewidth>1.0</linewidth>
      <color>-14090101</color>
      <bounds>
        <x>260.0</x>
        <y>750.0</y>
        <width>217.0</width>
        <height>18.0</height>
      </bounds>
      <sample>
        <x>260.625</x>
        <y>766.0</y>
        <time>1459867893629</time>
        <force>108</force>
      </sample>
      <sample>
        <x>260.625</x>
        <y>763.625</y>
        <time>1459867893722</time>
        <force>120</force>
      </sample>
      <sample>
        <x>262.875</x>
        <y>762.0</y>
        <time>1459867893775</time>
        <force>122</force>
      </sample>
      <sample>
        <x>278.0</x>
        <y>757.125</y>
        <time>1459867893935</time>
        <force>124</force>
      </sample>
      <sample>
        <x>294.875</x>
        <y>755.75</y>
        <time>1459867894015</time>
        <force>124</force>
      </sample>
      <sample>
        <x>304.875</x>
        <y>755.125</y>
        <time>1459867894055</time>
        <force>124</force>
      </sample>
      <sample>
        <x>319.125</x>
        <y>755.375</y>
        <time>1459867894109</time>
        <force>124</force>
      </sample>
      <sample>
        <x>474.25</x>
        <y>751.75</y>
        <time>1459867894802</time>
        <force>118</force>
      </sample>
      <sample>
        <x>469.875</x>
        <y>750.75</y>
        <time>1459867894815</time>
        <force>0</force>
      </sample>
    </stroke>
    <stroke>
      <starttime>1459867895892</starttime>
      <endtime>1459867896812</endtime>
      <linewidth>1.0</linewidth>
      <color>-14090101</color>
      <bounds>
        <x>364.0</x>
        <y>701.0</y>
        <width>10.0</width>
        <height>125.0</height>
      </bounds>
      <sample>
        <x>364.5</x>
        <y>701.0</y>
        <time>1459867895892</time>
        <force>32</force>
      </sample>
      <sample>
        <x>366.0</x>
        <y>702.0</y>
        <time>1459867895905</time>
        <force>106</force>
      </sample>
      <sample>
        <x>367.25</x>
        <y>702.625</y>
        <time>1459867895958</time>
        <force>120</force>
      </sample>
      <sample>
        <x>367.5</x>
        <y>703.125</y>
        <time>1459867896012</time>
        <force>122</force>
      </sample>
      <sample>
        <x>369.25</x>
        <y>724.125</y>
        <time>1459867896358</time>
        <force>126</force>
      </sample>
      <sample>
        <x>369.375</x>
        <y>748.0</y>
        <time>1459867896465</time>
        <force>126</force>
      </sample>
      <sample>
        <x>370.125</x>
        <y>765.0</y>
        <time>1459867896532</time>
        <force>126</force>
      </sample>
      <sample>
        <x>369.875</x>
        <y>779.5</y>
        <time>1459867896598</time>
        <force>126</force>
      </sample>
      <sample>
        <x>369.125</x>
        <y>789.125</y>
        <time>1459867896638</time>
        <force>126</force>
      </sample>
      <sample>
        <x>369.375</x>
        <y>795.25</y>
        <time>1459867896665</time>
        <force>126</force>
      </sample>
      <sample>
        <x>370.875</x>
        <y>803.75</y>
        <time>1459867896705</time>
        <force>126</force>
      </sample>
      <sample>
        <x>373.125</x>
        <y>825.625</y>
        <time>1459867896812</time>
        <force>126</force>
      </sample>
    </stroke>
  </UnassignedStrokes>
</page>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find rvest as the best package for dealing with the xml files.  Below is not a complete solution but it should be enough for you to start.

```
library(rvest)

myxml<-read_xml("text.xml")
#find the only the stroke nodes
stroke<-xml_nodes(myxml,"stroke")
#extract the start and end times
starttime<-xml_text(xml_nodes(stroke, "starttime"))
endtime<-xml_text(xml_nodes(stroke, "endtime"))
#find the bounds nodes under each stroke node
bounds<-xml_nodes(stroke, "bounds")
#extract out the x, y width and heigth from each bound node
x<-xml_text(xml_nodes(bounds, "x"))
y<-xml_text(xml_nodes(bounds, "y"))
width<-xml_text(xml_nodes(bounds, "width"))
height<-xml_text(xml_nodes(bounds, "height"))

#save to dataframe
df<-data.frame(starttime, endtime, x, y, width, height)
```

This code is assuming that each "stroke" node only has 1 start time, end time and 1 "bounds" node.  Since the there are multiple "sample" nodes in each parent "stroke" care will need to be taken to separate each subnode to the parent.  Here where I would start:

```
samples<-sapply(stroke, FUN=xml_nodes, xpath="sample")
```

Good luck.

Comment: ok, thanks at first! I understood the problem and try to solve it now :-)